# Styled HTML Submit button fails to respond to Return Key

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a simple HTML form, thus:

```
<form>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="text" />
    </p>
    <p class="buttonPara">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

and a simple stylesheet, thus:

```
p.buttonPara
{
    position: relative;
}
p.buttonPara input
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}
```

The submit button fails to respond to the return key unless I remove the class from the

```
<p class="buttonPara">
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: In which browser do you see this behaviour?

Comment: Does it fail even if you mousedown on the button, move off the button, mouseup and then press Return?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said (and you could have guessed) - IE8.  It works in Firefox.

Comment: Is the focus within the form area?

Comment: It fails when my cursor is sitting in the text box and works fine when the cursor is on the button.

Comment: It works fine if I remove the styling.  It appears to be caused by the "position: absolute".

Comment: It works fine for me with the code above. If I focus the button (or the text field) and hit Enter the form submits. Are you sure you are focusing the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

My **form** is contained in a **div** that has its **class** set programatically by the **body onload** event.  Until the **class** is set, the **div** has an underlying style of **display:none**.  In IE, the result is that hitting the return key does not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish and why you take this approach. Do you want to align the button in the middle of the textfield above?

You could do this without positioning the button element. But that would mean wrapping everything in a container element and setting the width of that element along with the text-align property. Or you could set the width and align properties of the form of course.

Comment: My website is fully "accessible" and button graphics are optional for the user.  The "buttonPara" also has a background-image and the button is moved to the right to accommodate it.  Those users who chose not to see graphics simply don't get the the stylesheet link, so the button appears in it's normal position.  All said, that's not the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: So, in that case, why not set the width of the form, or a wrapper div around the submit button, to something desirable and set the "text-align" property of that element to "right" in the scenario where the stylesheet is loaded.

Because working around the IE8 bug triggered by your approach might require some JavaScript hacking. Which will leave IE8 users who have disabled JavaScript out in the cold.